# Update external XIB objects programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, xib, viewcontroller

I have two XIB views loaded that are accessed through swipe gestures and would like to update my second XIB's textbox from my first XIB.

Here is the swift code I have so far but it appears that it doesn't work from one view to the other:

```
// This code is placed in ViewController0.xib
let vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle: nil)
vc1.resultsTextBox?.text = "test"        
// vc1.asd(1) //Tried calling a function that's in that view but it didn't work either.
```

Comment: This code creates a new instance of vc1. You need to get a reference to the instance of vc1 that is already loaded, probably by your root view controller that is manga going the swipe setting a property on vc0 when it loads vc1

Answer (score 0):

If resultsTextBox is a UITextField then it is likely not yet initialized. That is done in viewDidLoad. The better strategy is to set some string variable to "test". Then in viewDidLoad, set the resultsTextBox.text

```
let vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle: nil)
vc1.textBoxStr = "test"


override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  vc1.resultsTextBox?.text = textBoxStr
  ...
}
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: No luck. :-( My app already loads ViewController0 and ViewController1 initially and allows me to swipe between the two so I'll assume that the UITextField in ViewController1 is already initialized as I can see the initial text. However when I make updates from viewController0, with the code I've included above, updates are not made. Only updates to the UITextField are successful from ViewController1.

Comment: I see what you mean. Using the code above you will be creating a brand new ViewController1 in ViewController2, unless I am still missing something. If you are allowing to swipe between the two VCs then each of the VC should have a handle of the other, once instantiated VC.     let vc1 = ... then vc1.otherVC = vc2. Then same for vc2. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ahh, now it makes sense since I have been creating new instances the whole time. I've tried to do what you've suggested but I'm failing miserably while looking around for similar alternatives. I have posted a question with the code where my views are connected for swiping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36509356/global-data-update-on-slided-views-swift